# How to alert cookie in 30 character XSS payload?

Tags: xss

The application allows user to enter a 30 character long username.

I tried the following XSS payload and it worked, but the triager is asking if I can alert cookie. But script tags and src keyword is blocked.

```
"><iframe/onload=alert()>
```

Any way to load javascript from a short URL, such as `http://⑮.₨`?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Is there a reason you are linking to that strange looking URL? Are you looking for ways to load scripts from a URL in general?

Comment: yes :D. Its the shortest url that I can use to show impact. The character count of ⑮.₨ is just 2 that saves 2 character since its uni-code character. When interpreted by browser it actually become 15.rs.

Answer (score 2):

If you change `iframe` to `a` to save a few characters, you still need 13 characters just to set things up:

```
"><a onload=>
```

That leaves you 17 characters for the actual JavaScript payload. That is not enough for `alert(document.cookie)`. You could get an extra character by using `oncut` instead of `onload` but you still have to few.

So trying to load an external script is a reasonable idea. Problem is, you have to few characters for that too. You can get around the blocking of `script` and `src` by using things like `"scr"+"ipt"`, but you still run into the length limitation. If there is jQuery, you could almost make it with [`$.loadScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/), but only almost.

So what to do? I can see three options:

- See whats in the global namespace. Perhaps there is something you can use? If the site already put `document.cookie` in a global variable named `x` you are very lucky...
- Can you create multiple usernames with some sort of chained exploit? I.e. first one puts `document.cookie` in a variable named `x`, next one alerts it.
- Maybe I missed some clever way to write super compact JavaScript that you can use!